# How to use dockpanel to stretch a canvas?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```
<DockPanel Name="dcPanel">
    <Button Name="TopRect" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="LightGreen"
        Height="50" Content="Top" Margin="30,50,0,0" />
</DockPanel>
```

The code above stretch a button if I maximize the window.
How can I add a Canvas inside the dockpanel, so when I maximize the window, all the canvas content will be stretched?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DockPanel will stretch the Canvas, but the Canvas will never stretch it's children. The Canvas always uses the desired size of it's children when arranging them.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the Width, and Height to Auto. (of a canvas you can add)

**EDIT:**
I used this code, and it works perfectly:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Canvas Background="Black" />
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: dude, try adding a button -.-

Comment: As CodeNaked pointed out, it's impossible, try adding a dockpannel in the canvas, and you can see the prove that it can't be done, because a dockpanel usually consumes all space it has access too, that means that the canvas doesn't give that space. May I suggest using a `<grid>`?